# EntityFieldQuery with date field

Tags: database

I am running the following code, retrieving a list of job openings that will expire in 7 days.

```
$triggerDate = new DateTime();
$triggerDate->add(new DateInterval("P7D"));

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type','node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle','job')
  ->propertyCondition('status',1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_expires','value',$triggerDate->format('Y-m-d'),'=');
```

This is returning 0 jobs, even though I have several that will expire in 7 days.  For example, one of my job nodes, has the following value

```
[field_expires] => Array
     (
         [und] => Array
             (
                 [0] => Array
                     (
                         [value] => 2013-05-09T00:00:00
                         [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
                         [timezone_db] => America/Los_Angeles
                         [date_type] => date
                     )

             )

     )
```

When I leave the filter off altogether, the query succeeds and retrieves all items.  I've tried many variations of the date format including `Y-m-d\T00:00:00` and `Y-m-d 00:00:00`.

The field is of type: `Date (ISO format)`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to see in the database how is stored your `field_expires` ?

Comment: Y-m-d\TH:i:s really should work as far as formats go. Have you tried printing $triggerDate->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') just to see what it is passing to the query?

Comment: @rooby, yes, I have and it's showing me the date I expect to see.

Answer (score 4):

This works perfectly fine:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type','node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product_display')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_expires','value', '2013-04-30T14:02Z', '>')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However,the only problem with this is I need only those nodes from a given date, not all that come after as well, as a greater than operator would do.

Comment: Then maybe try   ->fieldCondition('field_expires','value', array('2013-04-30T00:00Z', '2013-04-30T11:59Z'), 'BETWEEN')

Comment: Maybe that is what your problem is, are you expecting that if you check for midnight it will give you all results on that day? - Because it won't, it will only give you results that are exactly midnight on the given date. You have to do a range to match the whole day.